# Tomcat Log4J problem - no appenders could be found

Tags: java, log4j

We have a very simple log4j setup for tomcat. We have only a single log4j.properties file and have added the debug flag at startup to verify that the correct log4j.properties file is being used.

Here is our configuration:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %.20t:%c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout2=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout2.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %.20t:%c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.com.rei.framework.model.Table=INFO, stdout2
log4j.logger.com.rei.framework.view.SqlGridDisplayGroup=WARN, stdout2
```

The problem we are having is that unless I specifically list a logger for each class I get this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.rei.util.DatabaseConnection).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

According to the docs the ROOT logger should be the default logger for any classes without a specific configuration line, yet I get many "No appenders found" warnings if I don't enumerate each class in the configuration. With hundreds of classes in our project this is not maintainable.

We instantiate the logger this way inside each class:

```
static Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Myclass.class);
```

Any ideas why the root logger in this configuration is not being picked up for undefined classes?

Comment: Use -Dlog4j.debug as a parameter to the JVM should help finding the problem.

Comment: Which version of log4j are you using? The above instantiation of the Logger seems weird: Usually it is something like static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log4jClass.class);

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my pasting of the code. I removed our class names intending to put generic names in the example and forgot to put them back in. I do indeed use the SomeClass.class syntax inside of Logger.getLogger.

Comment: Interestingly, I tested this problem for a new class and the root logger picked up the class just fine. So it is now apparent that this is only happening for some classes and not others. Also, outside of Tomcat this seems to be a non-issue and only occurs inside of Tomcat. That led me to believe I have multiple configuration files or multiple jar files, but I have confirmed that is not the case. Still pondering...

Comment: The line still seems wrong: you shouldn't have the new Logger. Surely just Logger.getLogger should work?

Comment: Do you have other logging frameworks in your lib directory of your tomcat installation? Also, could you tell if you're importing other logging frameworks in the class (such as apache commons-logging or java.util.logging?)

Comment: You are correct, the line was still wrong. I had it messed up because we actually were wrapping log4j in our own Logger class to provide some additional debugging. I have removed our wrapper and updated the code and still have the same results.

Comment: Yes, we are importing apache commons-logging. Will that create a conflict with log4j?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3207/discussion-between-davidethell-and-matthew-farwell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, log4j.rootLogger should be the default configuration. The behaviour that you're getting happens when you haven't got the line

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

in your file. I've tested with the above file, and this works for me. Therefore, in the file you're actually using, you don't have that line, or you're using a different version of log4j from me (I've tried with 1.2.9 to 1.2.16).

When you specify the -Dlog4j.debug on the command line, you should get output like:

```
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/developpement/mjf-workspace/Stackoverflow/lib/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/developpement/mjf-workspace/Stackoverflow/lib/log4j.properties
log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
log4j: Parsing for [com.rei.framework.model.Table] with value=[INFO, stdout2].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category com.rei.framework.model.Table set to INFO
```

Do you get the line:

```
log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
```

If you are getting that, then there is something wrong with your log4j.properties file. This is the java class I'm using to test:

```
package uk.co.farwell.stackoverflow;

import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class Log4jTest {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        logger.debug("hello Log4jTest");
    }
}
```

EDIT: It turns out that the Logger class that you're importing into the class and thus using is the Apache commons logging, not log4j. Apache commons logging uses rootCategory, not rootLogger (see [Configuring Log4J](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Configuring%20Log4J):

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
```

This is why it's not picking up the default logger. Try adding this line to your log4j.properties.

It's not a good idea to mix your logging frameworks, so pick one and stick with it. If commons logging works for you, use that. But don't mix and match in your code. It's a bad idea, and leads to a lot of confusion.

Personally, I always use **[slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)**. slf4j allows you to have one single configuration for multiple frameworks, so I use that by default. slf4j is often mandatory, because third party libraries use commons logging or even java logging, and you can't change this. slf4j uses a bridge so that everything turns up in the same place, and works too.

It also has a number of advtanges, such as [parameterized logging](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance).

Recommendation: use slf4j.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have tried the -Dlog4j.debug flag and verified that it is reading the correct log4j.properties file. It does not complain that it couldn't find a root logger.

Comment: Excellent edit! I will try this out and award the answer once I verify.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Removed all Apache commons-logging jar files and the issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `log4j.properties` is in the classpath!

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is in the classpath. The file is under WEB-INF/classes and I have made sure there are no other log4j.properties or xml files anywhere in tomcat. This is basically a one-app tomcat instance so I can be sure nothing else is interfering with our settings.

Comment: Where is your log4j JAR file ?

Comment: The jar file is in the webapp lib path: webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib